# Auto Deleting New Operator

Tags: c++

I was reading through the wxWidgets tutorial: http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_helloworld.html

And I noticed that they use new without delete. How is this possible :S How can you use new on a class without deleting it :S It doesn't make any sense to me :l

Can someone explain what's going on?

Comment: Classes can be coded to delete themselves with tricks like reference counting. Alternatively, they might use smart pointers or some other form of garbage collection. In this case, they seem to not be worried about leaking, since the O/S will free all the memory when the program exits. But this is **bad** practice.

Comment: @0A0D what does `delete` have to do with a destructor?

Comment: @NikBougalis:  If you want its memory to be freed and the destructor run, you have to delete it if it was allocated on the heap. If it was allocated on the stack this happens automatically (i.e. when it goes out of scope; see RAII). If it is a member of a class (not a pointer, but a full member), then this will happen when the containing object is destroyed.

Comment: @0A0D the OP asked whether you can use `new` without using `delete`. Of course you can, but it's bad form, and it has nothing to do with destructors. Your comment is meaningless and unhelpful.

Comment: @NikBougalis: " they use new without delete". Actually, your comment is not helpful. Did you read my comment? It explains to the OP the reason to use delete. I'm thinking you just want to be argumentative today.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the end of a program's execution, all memory in the process' memory space is freed by the OS.

It is likely that the tutorial showed you a simple example that requires the instantiated objects live until the end of the program.

For example, creating the window for the program will live until the program exits. So it is not necessary to delete this since the OS will do it for you.

I am not saying this is good practice, I always suggest that you explicitly take care of freeing memory to get in good habits.

There are other options in c++, such as smart pointers, which handle deletion of objects when refcounts reach 0, but I don't think that is what is happening here.

Comment: Hmmm.. I was very confused before reading this. I thought it was some magic that I could do for anything after seeing it but after reading this, I see what you mean. I think that's just lazy! Confused me for a second. I'll accept in 8 minutes because that's the stack-overflow timer. Thank you!

Comment: In this case, this isn't actually what is happening.

Comment: @75inchpianist: No, the code is managing the pointers completely by wxWidget framework and there is no memory leaking which needs finishing the execution to release resources.

Comment: How it can answer the question which is just talking about pointers generally? ... wxWidget manages the memory in its way.

Answer (score 2):

Some class libraries have a rule which gives the ownership of pointers as children to a parent object.

In this case, when you `new` an object and pass it to an owner object, it is the task of the owner to `delete` the pointer.

For example, a widget object adds GUI controls in its children-list, when the owner is going to be deleted, its destructor `delete` the children.

Read the [documentation](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Avoiding_Memory_Leaks#Child_windows) of wxWidgets about avoiding memory leaks:

> **Child windows**
>
> When a wxWindow is destroyed, it automatically deletes all its
>   children. These children are all the objects that received the window
>   as the parent-argument in their constructors.
>
> As a consequence, if you're creating a derived class that contains
>   child windows, you should use a pointer to the child windows instead
>   of the objects themself as members of the main window.

Answer (score 1):

You CAN use New without Delete, but only if you want the lifetime of the object to last until the program exits. Generally, it IS considered bad form.

Comment: Er, this isn't about Qt and even if it was, Qt deletes child objects automatically when the parents are deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to use `new` without calling `delete` but in general it's bad form. However just because you call `new` without *explicitly* calling `delete` yourself does not mean it is not called. In regards to GUI frameworks many of them handle calling `delete` internally based on external events. For instance if you call `new` to create an object that represents a window the GUI framework  *may* call `delete` when the OS destroys the window. It may not be obvious unless you are familiar with the framework or read the documentation for it.

There are also "smart pointers" which are objects that hold a pointer to a particular resource and release (delete) it when the smart pointer itself is destroyed. Boost and C++11 provide implementations of smart pointers (`std::unique_ptr` for instance) which are used quite often to manage the lifetime (and ownership) of objects created using `new`. This of course is a generalization of smart pointers as there are various implementations that use reference counting or other mechanisms to ensure that the resource is released only when it is no longer used.

There are many articles floating around the web concerning smart pointers, resource lifetime, resource ownership, etc. A quick Stackoverflow or Google Dance for "C++ smart pointers" will give you a vary large list of resources for further reading. Searching for the acronyms RAII and SBRM will also bring up a large list of resources.

Answer (score 0):

This has got to do with the way the `wxFrame` class is implemented. The object will be deleted when the frame is closed.

Quoting the [wxWidgets documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_windowdeletionoverview.html):

> The default close event handler for wxFrame destroys the frame using Destroy().

Typically you do need to delete objects you allocate with the new, but in this case someone else is doing it for you.